# How to update Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 without graphic card (nVidia) problems?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.04

I usually have problems when upgrade Ubuntu with nVidia graphics card. Is there any way to prevent these potential problems **before** updating?

Change to the Nouveau driver before updating solve me the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If you fear that your drivers will cause problems during your upgrade, I would consider:

- Removing the nvidia proprietary drivers.
- Upgrading your distro.
- Installing the nvidia proprietary drivers.

If this yet again fails, you can get into your installation through recovery or using nomodeset during your bootup and removing the nvidia drivers and look for a solution.

Please let me know how you get on.